# Как решить рекуррентную формулу?

Tags: python

Пробовал через `while`, ничего не получилось:

```
while n_n<=n_k:
    n_n+=1
    n+=1
    i=pow(n,1/n+1)
    s+=i
```

Ребят, помогите кодом(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А что, если двигаться "изнутри наружу": сначала считаем корень из n, придавляем к нему n-1, извлекаем из этого корень, и так далее, до тех пор, пока под корнем не окажется "единица плюс результат предыдущих вычислений".

Comment: здесь нужно раскручивать рекурсию изнутри и всегда брать __квадратный__ корень из суммы N-1 и предыдущего шага

Answer (score 5):

Вариант без рекурсии:

```
n = 4
res = 0
while n > 0:
    res = (res + n) ** 0.5
    n -= 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Вариант с рекурсией:

```
def rec_sqr(n, i=1):
    return n**.5 if i==n else (i + rec_sqr(n, i+1))**.5
```

Comment: Даже доделать код не могу, вот я овощь((